# How to add an email library in an existing nodejs server

Tags: node.js, webserver

I have a web server which is implemented using NodeJs. Now I want to add a functionality which will send a group of people email alerts if an event occurs. But I do not know how to add this feature in the existing code. I researched online and found sendgrid-nodejs but I do not know if that would work or not. I am not sure how to start. Please help.

Comment: Do you use SendGrid?  If so, their client library would be useful to you.  If not, it won't be.  You're looking for an SMTP client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out [nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) module.

The website has many different examples which you can follow.

Here is a one of those examples:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport();
transporter.sendMail({
  from: 'sender@address',
  to: 'receiver@address',
  subject: 'hello',
  text: 'hello world!'
});
```